# Babelify omit file extension on import

Tags: reactjs, browserify, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I am writing a [React](https://facebook.github.io/react/) application with [ES6](https://github.com/lukehoban/es6features) and [JSX](https://jsx.github.io/). Below is the command I use to browserify my `.es6` files into a `bundle.js`.

```
$ browserify src/es6/app.es6 -t babelify -o build/js/bundle.js
```

When I try to import a component using something like `import MenuBar from './menu'`, I get the error message:

```
Error: Cannot find module './menu'
```

The only workaround I found is adding `.es6` to the file name (`import MenuBar from './menu.es6'`), which isn't very appealing to look at.

Is there a way to let [browserify](http://browserify.org/) or [babelify](https://github.com/babel/babelify) know which extensions to use when importing modules?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try:

```
browserify src/es6/app.es6 -t babelify -o build/js/bundle.js \
--extension=.js --extension=.json --extension=.es6
```

Babelify should handle `.es6` by default on its end.

By the way, if you can you're often better off writing scripts against the browserify API rather than using the CLI. In this case it'd be something like:

```js
var
  browserify = require('browserify'),
  babelify = require('babelify'),
  path = require('path'),
  fs = require('fs');

browserify('src/es6/app.es6', {
  extensions: ['.js', '.json', '.es6'],
})
  .transform(babelify)
  .bundle()
  .pipe(fs.createWriteStream(path.join(__dirname, 'build/js/bundle.js')));
```

Comment: Oh hey it worked :D Learning something new every day~ Thanks!

Comment: Great, thanks. By the way, I updated my answer with a note and example about using the API.

Comment: I was having issues getting browserify + babelify + @babel/preset-typescript to resolve Typescript imports when one of my source files would import a TS file without the extension (e.g. a.js imports b.ts via `import Foo from "./b"`). I needed to both pass --extension=.ts --extension=.js to browserify _and_ pass --extensions '.ts,.js' to babelify, e.g. `browserify ... -t [ babelify --extensions '.ts,.js' ] --extension=.js extension=.ts`